# google Forms script to shut off responses every Friday, restart Saturday

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to shut off Forms responses at 5 PM every Friday with a custom message that responses are closed and will reopen on Saturday noon.  I then need to reopen the responses on Saturday noon.  Please help with code to do this.  Many, many thanks.
Peter

Comment: [setAcceptingResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setAcceptingResponses(Boolean))

Answer (score 0):

If you get a lot of responses then you could probably just attach this function to the onFormSubmit and not need a timebased trigger.

```
function formOnOf(id,msg) {
  var dt=new Date();
  var day=dt.getDay();
  var hour=dt.getHour();
  if(hour>17 && day==5) {
    var form=FormApp.openById(id)
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
    form.getCustomClosedFormMessage(msg)
  }
  if(hour>12 && day==6) {
    FormApp.openById(id).setAcceptingResponses(true);
  }
  if(day<5) {
    FormApp.openById(id).setAcceptingResponses(true);
  }
}
```

[getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours)

[getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

[getCustomClosedFormMessage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form.html#getCustomClosedFormMessage())

[[setAcceptResponses(boolean)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setAcceptingResponses(Boolean))